# create array with in foreach in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am facing problems in arrays i would like to add on array with in  multidimentional array .  thank you my intension is dynamically check an array with some values if those values
   are not present i ll add them

my code is:

```
$a=array(array(1,2,3),
    array(4,5,6),
    array(7,8,9),
    array(10,11,12),
);

foreach($a as &$b){
array_push($b,array(1,1,1));

} 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
```

required output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3


    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 6


    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 9


    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 11
        [2] => 12

    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
    )


)
```

but im getting like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 1
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 6
        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 1
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 9
        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 1
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 11
        [2] => 12
        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Post the code that you wrote

Comment: Well then... change your code. We can't suggest anything, since you don't show any.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array(
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(4, 5, 6),
    array(7, 8, 9),
    array(10, 11, 12)
);

array_push($a, array(1, 1, 1));
// or
$a[] = array(1, 1, 1);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
```

Comment: this gives an error:Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16 bytes) on line 8

Comment: No it doesn't. http://3v4l.org/DUhGf

Comment: with in foreach i would like to add

Comment: What precisely do you want to do? The above code is an example for how you get the output you expect, as asked in your question. If you want something else, ask for something else. If you're running out of memory, you're likely creating an infinite loop. Maybe you need to go back to reading a bit more about the basics using a tutorial or book. I'm not saying this to put you down, I'm saying this because it will likely be more productive for you as well.

Comment: thank you my intension is dynamically check an array with some values if those values are not present i ll add them

Answer (score 0):

no foreach are required for this case, after looking at your required output.

I think only pushing the array you want ...
like this:

```
$a=array(array(1,2,3),
  array(4,5,6),
  array(7,8,9),
  array(10,11,12),
);
array_push($a,array(1,1,1));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);
```

Hope it help

Comment: thank you my intension is dynamically check an array with some values if those values are not present i ll add them

Answer (score -1):

try something like:

```
$array=array(
    array(4,5,6),
    array(7,8,9),
    array(10,11,12),
    array(1,1,1)    
);
```

EDIT: how to fill the array within a loop.

I'll use a `while` since it's a bit more clear.

```
$x=1;
$array=array();
while($x<6){
    $array[$x]=array(1+$x*3, 2+$x*3, 3+$x*3);
    $x++;
}
```

This should output a matrix like:

```
(4 ,  5,  6)
(7 ,  8,  9)
(10, 11, 12)
(13, 14, 15)
```

Comment: thank you,but my intention is i can add an array with in for each please help me

Comment: well, tbh it's better to try something on your own, post it if you don't know why it isn't working, then we can help with it. Anyway i'll update my answer with a example that may help you.

Comment: it is relate to my project